# use LINQ on XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

```
<X version="1.0">
  <Y id="abc" abv="a"/>
  <Y id="edf" abv="e"/>
</X>
```

I want to select the node whose id is "abc", and return its abv "a".

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(filePath);
XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("X/Y");
var node = list.Cast<XmlNode>().Where(node => node["id"].InnerText == "abc")
                               .Select(x=>x["abv"].InnerText);
```

But it does't work, node["id"].InnerText is always "". Can you point out where is a problem?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Well, your xml node has no inner text. `<Y id="abc" abv="a">This is the inner text</y>`. I forgot the exact property, but it's most likely something like `node.Attributes["id"].Value == "abc"` and `Select(x => x.Attributes["abv"].Value)`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `InnerText` for a node is the text that appears between `<node>` and `</node>`. So for, eg `<Y attributes />` there is no inner text.

You need to use `node => node.Attributes["id"].Value == "abc"`

Answer (score 38):

Aside from the fact what your code snippet wouldn't be compiled because of non-unique `node` variable (first outside of linq query and second in "where" method lambda), you have also missed `Attributes` in your query.

It should be something like

```
var node = list.Cast<XmlNode>()
               .Where(n => n.Attributes["id"].InnerText == "abc")
               .Select(x => x.Attributes["abv"].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just cast XmlNodeList to List, like that:

```
            List<XmlNode> list = new List<XmlNode>();

            foreach(XmlNode a in xmlNodeList)
            {
                list.Add(a);
            }
            list.OrderBy((element) => element.ChildNodes[0].InnerText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is better to use `OfType<XmlElement>` instead of `Cast<XmlNode>`